# Get Facebook friends id in swift

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift

I've got the Facebook SDK working, but I'm not sure exactly how to get a list of Facebook friends and their ids?

I found this code, but it doesn't quite seem to work, could someone show me how to access the list of names and ids?

```
// Get List Of Friends
var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()
friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection:FBRequestConnection!,
    result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
var resultdict = result as NSDictionary
println("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")
var data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
```

In the following line there is an error that I can fix by replacing `0..<data.count` with `0...data.count`, will this change anything?

```
for i in 0..<data.count {
    let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as NSDictionary
    let id = valueDict.objectForKey("id") as String
    println("the id value is \(id)")
}

var friends = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
    println("Found \(friends.count) friends")
}
```

It should return data like:

```
Result Dict: {
     data = (
              {
                "first_name" = Brian;
                id = <FACEBOOK FRIEND FACEBOOK ID>;
                "last_name" = Coleman;
                name = "Brian Coleman";
              }
            );
     paging =  {
       next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/<LOGGED IN FACEBOOK USER ID>/friends?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name&format=json&access_token=<FACEBOOK TOKEN USED BY YOUR APP>&offset=5000&__after_id=<ENCREYPTED ID>";
     };
     summary =     {
        "total_count" = 1;
     };
}
```

Additionally, in "summary" I get the right number of friends, but that doesn't seem to transfer elsewhere, such as when I try to print the number of friends.

Comment: You are aware that from API v2 on your app will only be able to get friends of the user that are also users of the app, right?

Comment: Now that you mention it I do remember reading that! Theres my problem! Thanks for such a quick response.

Comment: @CBroe you just saved my tons of hours! Thank you for your comment!